# Can't change app badge in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, uiapplication

I am trying to add badge to app icon but simply nothing happens.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 40;
```

Do I miss something in this code?

Comment: I have checked your code and it is showing 40 Badges in my app icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you ask for permission to change badge? This has been changed in iOS8 and require a specific permission:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge, 
                                        categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Answer (score 0):

register for remote notification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge, 
                                        categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        return true
    }
```

Update your badge number

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are old.

iOS 10 and up:

```
let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound, .badge];             
UNUserNotificationCenter.current()(options: options) { (granted, error) in
    //print("granted: \(granted)")
    if let error = error {
        print("Error requestAuthorization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }                   
}
```